# How can I make the selling phases less laborious?

Tags: far-cry-3

Selling stuff is an easy way to make money in Far Cry 3.  But the store doesn't seem really convenient: I spend precious minutes to double click (or double tap <kbd>Enter</kbd>) to sell everything as fast as I can.  It's even more painfull when I want to quick-sell craft items (leaves or animal skins), because I have to deal with a confirmation pop-up.

Is it possible to make it faster ?  By multi-selecting items, for instance, or just selling the whole content of your bag in one click ?

Comment: There is an auto-sell of garbage loot.  Is that what you are trying to refer to?

Comment: Where ? I'm refering to anything that could make the selling less painful...  :o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are at a vendor, you can auto-sell loot that has no real purpose in the game besides making money at a vendor.  Go to the sell tab, and select the auto sell trash loot.

Another option would be to **Select Quick Sell**, which will sell all of the same items selected.

Here is a great explanation on how to use quick sell @ 1 min in:

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks *a lot*.

Comment: Anytime, sorry it took so long to find lol

Comment: This does not solve any problems when it comes to selling herbs and leather. That was - if I got it right - the dentral point of the question (and also my problem).